# How to storage checkbox values to a field of mysql for search?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to storage checkbox valus to a field.

#### html like this

`two value selected`

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">invest_type1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" checked>invest_type2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" checked>invest_type3
<!-- more, but less than 20-->
```

#### mysql table dict

```
id
project_name
invest_types   // how to save?
// other fields
```

#### Demand

`multiple select`

exp. User select "invest1" and "invest2",then how to fetch that row?

#### Plans

1. use bit method to storage.

   invest_type2 is 2 , pow(2,2) => 4

   invest_type2 is 3 , pow(2,3) => 8

   4+8=12,when select use invest_types & (invest_type1's pow + invest_type2's pow)
2. add table to relate

   add table to storage invest_types with every project.

   use join and distinct when use search.

#### Problem & Help

- Which plan is the best?
- What about efficiency of plan1?

Answer (score 0):

> Which plan is the best?

It depends on your ER model. If you only need to store and search trough those preferences I will go with plan1.
Instead if you need to associate those preferences to multiple related entities I will go with plan2

> What about efficiency of plan1?

Your proposed plan1 can be very efficient, in fact you can use php bitwise functions (`http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php`) to create the values you will save into the db and then use the mysql bitwise functions to retrieve and search on it (`http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html`)